# How could i split the string in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, split, query-string

```
   private fun handleDynamicLink() {
    Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            val deepLink: Uri?
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link

                  deepLink?.getQueryParameter("inviteCode")?.let{connecttest(it)}
```

inviteCode string which is generating value of

```
https://example.com/?inviteCode=myuser?myToken%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ
```

I want to split this it into strings

```
inviteCode =myuser; & myToken = eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ;
```

want to use those values here:

```
private fun connecttest (inviteCode: String, myToken: String) {
    MeetingUtils.starttest(
        this,
        inviteCode,
        myToken
 ) // Start Test
```

}

How to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use multiple replace and split calls

If this is the Url

```
https://example.com/?inviteCode=myuser?myToken%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ
```

Then you can call

```
val splitUrl =url.replace("https://example.com/?inviteCode=","").split("?")
val user = splitUrl[0]
val token = splitUrl[1].replace("myToken%","")
```

Edit: The replace parts are only for removing those parts, replacing them with empty Strings.